Unable to run multiple SQL scripts on Spring boot startup
I'm trying to run two different SQL scripts when my Java application starts. One for creating the schemas and one for inputting test data. I'd like to keep them separated so I don't have the edit both files if I have to change something about the schemas in the future.
This is the part from my application-dev.properties where I try to run both scripts:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:devdb;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'src/main/resources/SQL_script.sql'\;RUNSCRIPT FROM 'src/main/resources/H2_data.sql'

This is the error I'm getting from the console in IntelliJ
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: URL format error; must be "jdbc:h2:{ {.|mem:}[name] | [file:]fileName | {tcp|ssl}:[//]server[:port][,server2[:port]]/name }[;key=value...]" but is "jdbc:h2:mem:devdb" [90046-224]

When I try to only execute one statement, to create the schemas for example, there are no issues.
I'm still fairly new at programming and therefore I'm not sure how to troubleshoot the issue. I've tried asking ChatGPT which just kept telling me to check for typos.
I am expecting the SQL_script.sql to run first and create the schemas, afterwards the H2_data script should run and insert test data into my dev database.

Spring Boot out-of-the-box supports a schema.sql and data.sql for which you don't need to configure anything. So rename your files accordingly, and ditch the spring.datasource.url property (spring boot will automatically create an in-memory database anyway if it detects H2).

If you are using Springboot, as obvious from your post, the application properties file spring.data.url.
So, for automatic Schema creation you can use spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update, it will update when there is any changes on your model classes or Entity classes, annotated with @Entity.
There are other options for ddl-auto like create, create-drop, none, validate
For data initialization, you can add spring.sql.init.mode = always and for loading data onto SQL application on botstrap, you can place sql file on project folder, and mention by spring.sql.init.data-locations on application.properties file.
For details you can check Spring Data initialization guide

Thanks for your reply! While I have no doubt your method would work, I think it may be a bit too complicated for where I'm at. This project is for my upcoming exam, and would not be able to explain any of it. Do you know if there's any way to do it the way I have 'started', or is there a reason it should not work?
